# Should a cloned obj pass equals() of the original?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design

Pretty much what the title says. I'm asking with Java in mind; however, I'm not limiting the premise to java. Would it be considered counter-intuitive to have a cloned object not pass equals function?

Comment: In other words - when does one need to override `equals` - which has been asked a dozen times on Stackoverflow before, see, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134050/when-do-i-need-to-override-equals-and-hashcode-method. If you do not override, your cloned object does not "pass equals". If you override, you will typically implement value equality, which means a cloned object will "pass equals".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. For most classes, the value of the object determines equality, so a cloned object should be equal to the original. There are classes where the identity of the object determines equality, that is objects are equal if and only if they are the same object. In such cases, a cloned object is a different object and should not compare equal.

Comment: IMO value equality should only be used for immutable objects, in which case cloning is of limited utility (optimizing slices into a big array is one of the few exceptions).

Comment: CodesInChaos is correct, but there is another concept, "equivalence", which can be applied to mutable structures. Unfortunately, this concept is rarely formal.

Answer (score 2):

A cloned object is supposed to bear the same characteristics as the original, so in general it should be `equal` to it. The only stronger criterion would be *identity*, and most programming languages already have a `==` operator for that. Therefore, it would make no sense to have a second, weaker `equals` operator and then define a clone as not satisfying it.

Comment: Unfortunately the terminology is very vague... sometimes "equal" and "identical" mean the same thing.

Comment: Usually if one clone an object, then he want cloned object to be considered equals to the original object. For example, you might clone an object then later want to compare if both objects are still equals.